# Rails: loop comparing two arrays and pushing matches to new array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, comparison

I have two arrays that I need to check against each other. When a match is found I need to unset the value from the first array and push that value to a new array.

Here is an example:

First Array `import_data`

```
["mario", "blue", "SGC", "CJ672PA0"], 
["solid snake", "green", "NID", "VI6965KD"], 
["samus", "maroon", "TRUST", "DNYU6539"], 
["deckard cain", "purple", "JAFA", "SJW252MZ"],
["wedge", "yellow", "WALTER", "UJ28NVM1"]
```

Second Array `current_data`

```
["gordon", "orange", "DRONE", "OGJR8C0D"], 
["samus", "black", "TRUST", "DNYU6539"], 
["commander shepard", "red", "WHX", "TH985OI3"]
```

Notice that "samus" appears in both arrays with all the same data but a change to the color.

**My intent** is to loop through `import_data` and check the last index of each item in the array (the 8-digit "id") and compare that against `current_data`. Each time a "match" is found (based on the 8-digit "id") I want to push that item into a new array `update_data` and then I want to `unset` that match in the  `import_data` array.

**The problem** is that both arrays are of differing lengths. So as soon as my loop goes beyond the length of one item it can no longer check that index which results in an error.

My code essentially looks like this:

```
import_data.each_with_index do |data, index|
  if data[3] == current_data[index].id
    # @update_data << somehow push all of the data
  end
end
```

The reason this isn't working is because the length of `import_data` is longer than that of `current_data`. This results in the error:

**"undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass"**

Ideally the end result would be as follows:

"samus" has been removed from the `import_data` array and pushed to the `update_data` array

`import_data` array after loop

```
["mario", "blue", "SGC", "CJ672PA0"], 
["solid snake", "green", "NID", "VI6965KD"], 
--- 
["deckard cain", "purple", "JAFA", "SJW252MZ"],
["wedge", "yellow", "WALTER", "UJ28NVM1"]
```

Newly populated array `update_data`

```
 ["samus", "maroon", "TRUST", "DNYU6539"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the answer of Prakash works, I think this is more straightforward:

```
import_data = [
  ["mario", "blue", "SGC", "CJ672PA0"], 
  ["solid snake", "green", "NID", "VI6965KD"], 
  ["samus", "maroon", "TRUST", "DNYU6539"], 
  ["deckard cain", "purple", "JAFA", "SJW252MZ"],
  ["wedge", "yellow", "WALTER", "UJ28NVM1"]
]
current_data = [
  ["gordon", "orange", "DRONE", "OGJR8C0D"], 
  ["samus", "black", "TRUST", "DNYU6539"], 
  ["commander shepard", "red", "WHX", "TH985OI3"]
]

current_ids = current_data.map {|c| c[3]}

update_data = import_data.inject([]) do |result, data|
  result << import_data.delete(data) if current_ids.include?(data[3])
  result
end
```

After run you get:

```
update_data = [
  ["samus", "maroon", "TRUST", "DNYU6539"]
]
import_data = [
  ["mario", "blue", "SGC", "CJ672PA0"], 
  ["solid snake", "green", "NID", "VI6965KD"], 
  ["deckard cain", "purple", "JAFA", "SJW252MZ"],
  ["wedge", "yellow", "WALTER", "UJ28NVM1"]
]
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish what you are doing:

```
import_data = [ 
                ["mario", "blue", "SGC", "CJ672PA0"], 
                ["solid snake", "green", "NID", "VI6965KD"], 
                ["samus", "maroon", "TRUST", "DNYU6539"], 
                ["deckard cain", "purple", "JAFA", "SJW252MZ"],
                ["wedge", "yellow", "WALTER", "UJ28NVM1"]
              ]

current_data = [
                 ["gordon", "orange", "DRONE", "OGJR8C0D"], 
                 ["samus", "black", "TRUST", "DNYU6539"], 
                 ["commander shepard", "red", "WHX", "TH985OI3"]
                ]
```

Find the keys for both the arrays:

```
import_data_keys = import_data.map { |x| x[3] }
=> ["CJ672PA0", "VI6965KD", "DNYU6539", "SJW252MZ", "UJ28NVM1"]
current_data_keys = current_data.map { |x| x[3] }
=> ["OGJR8C0D", "DNYU6539", "TH985OI3"]
```

Find the common keys by intersecting these two arrays:

```
common_keys = import_data_keys & current_data_keys
=> ["DNYU6539"]
```

Use `common_keys` to delete from `import_data` and push to `update_data`.

```
common_keys.each do |key|
  import_data.each_with_index do |data, index|
    if data[3] == key
      update_data << import_data[index]
      import_data.delete_at(index)
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Note: The `break` statement is for stopping with that iteration after the element is found and processed.